# Git Bash how to remove empty line after command executed in terminal

Tags: git-bash

I update the Windows version Git Bash to 3.0.2, now I faced a very annoying problem, it is hard to be explained. In the terminal, after each command is executed, it will always automatically add a new empty line, for example:

```
User@path $ CMD-1
                         <<-- new line
User@path $ CMD-2
                         <<-- new line
User@path $ CMD-3
                         <<-- new line
User@path $
```

It is showing like the picture:
[image]

**My question is how can I remove this type of command-tail new line?**

And even further, which source file is adding those tail-new-lines after every command executed? Cause I have almost checked every file that related to `PS1` and inputs, but I still can't figure out why this stupid feature happens. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12):

This is caused by how your [PS1](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PS1) shell variable is configured.

If you run the following command in Git Bash it will print the current value of your `$PS1` variable:

```
echo "$PS1"
```

For example, the default value of `$PS1` on my computer is set to:

> ```
> \[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$
>                                 ^^                                                                                       ^^
> ```

**Note:** Yours will appear differently to what is shown above because I'm using an earlier version of Git Bash. However, what is important to note is the two newline characters `\n` (I've added caret symbols `^^` to clearly indicate them). The value of your `$PS1` will probably have just one newline character `\n`.

Essentially it's these/this newline (`\n`) character(s) that produce the blank newline after running a command.

---

#### Solution:

To remove the *"command-tail new line"* consider running the following compound command:

```
echo $'\n'"export PS1='${PS1//\\n/}'" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

**Explanation:**

- This essentially adds new code to either;

  1. The end of your existing [`.bash_profile`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) startup file (if the file *does* already exists in your [`HOME`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-HOME) directory).
  2. Or at the beginning of a newly created `.bash_profile` file in your home directory (if the file *does not* already exist).

  For instance, your `.bash_profile` file will now include a line that reads something like this:

  > `export PS1='<newvalue>'`
- The line that is is added to `.bash_profile` utilizes [`export`](https://ss64.com/bash/export.html) to define a new value for the `$PS1` shell variable. The `<newvalue>` part will actually be whatever your current PS1 value is minus any newline `\n` characters.
- The part that reads `${PS1//\\n/}` in the aforementioned compound command utilizes [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to remove all newline characters from your current `$PS1` value.

After running the aforementioned compound command the *"command-tail new line"* issue should be resolved the next time you create a new session, (i.e. create a new window, or relaunch Git Bash).

---

#### Edit: Changing `PS1` value in the `git-prompt.sh` file:

If you don't want to override the default `PS1` value using the aforementioned solution, you can change the value(s) in the `git-prompt.sh` file that Git Bash creates during installation.

To do this:

1. Open the file named `git-prompt.sh` in your code editor. The file is typically located at:

   `C:/Program Files/Git/etc/profile.d/git-prompt.sh`
2. Find instances of newline characters, i.e. `\n` and delete them.

   For instance; my `git-prompt.sh` file contained a couple of lines that read:

   ```
   PS1="$PS1"'\n'
   ```

   I simple deleted the `'\n'` part so that they read:

   ```
   PS1="$PS1"
   ```
3. Save the changes that you made to the `git-prompt.sh` file, then create a new session, (i.e. create a new window, or relaunch Git Bash).